# Redirect help on .htaccess file

Tags: url-rewrite

I want to put a Magento Redirect rule to change the Blog URL.

FROM: 
http://site.com/blog/cat/pets/page/2/

TO:
http://site.com/blog/pets/page/2/

So, basically I want to remove the /cat. Also, there are hundreds of pages on our blog. so page number is different for each URL.

thanks,
/pj

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /cat/$1 [L,QSA]
```